# Upgrade from 32Bit to 64Bit?

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit

***Do not ask me to read the similar questions because I already did and my question is different***

There is an idea about saving the current machine stat in a virtual machine *(virtualizing a physical machine)* and save it in an external storage then install 64 Bit system and install the virtual machine to reinstall all the programs , services , registry keys and the files . So with this way I will be able to upgrade from 32 Bit to 64 Bit without reinstalling my programs , so does anyone of you have any idea about that If it is then share it with me here please ?(I'm using windows 10)

Comment: Your question is the same as the many "is there any way to upgrade from a 32-bit Windows OS to a 64-bit Windows OS without reinstalling applications" questions. The way you're suggesting won't work for the reason explained in the answers to all those other questions.

Comment: "So with this way I will be able to upgrade from 32 Bit to 64 Bit without reinstalling my programs , so does anyone of you have any idea about that If it is then share it with me here please ?(I'm using windows 10)" No You will not, and your question, is identical to those other questions.

Comment: I am indeed that stupid

Comment: @Ramhound  lol...

Comment: @Moab When meet with stupidity at that level only one way to react to it.

Comment: @Ramhound "never argue with an idiot as they will bring you down to their level and beat you with experience".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that can't possibly work. The 64-bit versions of those programs and their components *aren't installed on your 32-bit system*. So you have to install them all.

When you run an installer on a 32-bit operating system, it installs the 32-bit versions of the program's components in the correct locations for a 32-bit operating system. A 64-bit operating system would require different components in different places. The only way to get them there is to run the installer.

Comment: this is more logic than your first comment ;) . but i think that the virtual machine program will do all of this , will take the programs from tha 32 bit image and put them in the right place in the new 64 bit place , i'm just thinking :) explain for me please

Comment: I really don't have the patience to explain why every thing you make up with no basis in fact or reason is incorrect. If you can explain some reason to think that a virtual machine program moves applications, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Thank you anyway , because i have many programs in y computer and reinstalling them could take days that's why :)

Comment: I've put off reinstalling Windows on my main desktop for four years now because of fear of lost productivity. You can try to save your existing Windows installation as a VM or buy a new hard drive (or SSD) at the same time so you can, if need be, put the old drive back in.

Comment: :) It's a common problem ^_^

Answer (score -3):

You could use [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) Microsoft Sysinternals tool to capture a VHD of your Hard Drive(s), which you could then mount onto a virtualisation software ([VMWare Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads), [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) to use within the virtual machine. There is no way, however, to 'import' your 32-Bit applications into your 64-Bit Windows 10 install, you'll need to re-download the relevant versions to install onto the new install.

Comment: when I will be able to vote you I will do (thank you anyway for your help ^_^ ) waawia

Comment: sorry for the dislikes you've got from the others here :(